# Postgres - Get data from each alias

Tags: postgresql

In my application i have a query that do multiple joins with a table position. Just like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (...) as trips
join trip as t on trips.trip_id = t.trip_id

left outer join vehicle as v on v.vehicle_id = t.trip_vehicle_id

left outer join position as start on trips.start_position_id = start.position_id and start.position_vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id

left outer join position as "end" on trips.end_position_id = "end".position_id and "end".position_vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id

left outer join position as last on trips.last_position_id = last.position_id and last.position_vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id;
```

My table position has 35 columns(for example position_id).

When I run the query, in result should appear the table position 3 times, start, end and last. But postgres can not distinguish between, for exemplar, start.position_id, end.position_id and last.position_id. So this 3 columns are group and appear as one, position_id.

As the data from start.position_id and end.position_id are different, the column, position_id, that appear in result, it's empty.

Without having to rename all the columns, like this: start.position_id as start_position_id.

How can i get each group of data separately, for exemple, get all columns from the table 'start'. In MYSQL i can do this operation by calling fetch_fields, and give the function an alias, like 'start'.

But i can i do this in Postgres?

Best Regards,
Nuno Oliveira

Comment: Your query looks (at least) incomplete. But I'll format it a bit for you anyway.

Comment: yes its incomplete, i just put the parte that im having problems with. Its an huge query!! Thank you

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question. Are you just too lazy to type the list of column names in the `SELECT ...` clause?

Comment: No, i have a huge query. And the table position has a lot of columns too. Im going to try to do again the question.

Comment: I think it's better explained now! Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you can't (or find it difficult to) discern between which table each column with a shared name (such as "position_id") belongs to, but only need to see one of the sets of shared columns at any one time. If that is the case, use `tablename.*` in your SELECT, so `SELECT trips.*, start.*...` would show the columns from trips and start, but no columns from other tables involved in the join.

`SELECT  [...,] start.*  [,...] FROM [...] atable AS start [...]`

Comment: It's not that! That i know how to do it. The problem is different!
i have start.position_id, end.position_id and last.position_id. This 3 columns are grouped, but they shouldn't be. I want to know if there are a function that given the alias, for exemple start, the function will fetch the data from columns, start.position_id, start.position_time, etc...